# How many people have their first and last name beginning with the same letter?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, pigeonhole-principle

In a country, with a population of 11.000.000 people, how many of them have their first and last name beginning with the same letter? (e.g. Alex Abus, Peter Pen etc.) . Consider that their alphabet has 26 letters and that everyone has exactly one first name and one last name.
I have tried the upper problem and the following is my "solution". 
Can somebody please ensure me that is right or if its wrong explain to me the reason and give me the right solution?

```
Considering the Generalized Pigeonhole Principle:
at least
11.000.000 / 26 = 423.077 people have their first name beginning with the same letter.

From these 432.077 people, 
at least
432.077 / 26 = 16.619 people have their first AND last name beginning with the same letter.
```

Comment: There are of course more than 26 letters ...

Comment: There are people having just one name, like "Madonna". Of course, you can define the name then as "Madonna Madonna", to have a first and second name.

Comment: It's obviously not possible to answer this from the information given.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not to mention ☥ :)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich One thing you can say for sure. It's somewhere between $0$ and $11,000,000$.

Comment: I updated my question with more info, please check it.

Comment: At any rate, even restricting to the situation of everybody having a first name and a last name beginning with one of the 26 basic latin letters, there is no guarantee that *any* of them has an alliterating name. Your calculation only shows trhat there are 16619 people sharing the same monogram

Comment: The new information doesn't help. It could be everyone has initials AA, giving 11,000,000. Or it could be everyone has initials  AB, giving 0. (If you assime  the names are random and the last initial is indepedent of the first _then_ you can say something...)

Comment: If the question was only about their first name beginning with the same letter, 423.077 would be the right answer. In this question, I took the same logic and applied it again the GPPrinciple. Maybe this question needs to be solved with another way (e.g. combinations) .

Comment: The question you answer is that there is one pair of initions (say $M J$) that has at least $\frac {11,000,000}{26^2}$ people with it.  Not how many people have alliterative initials.

Comment: You can't use the pigeon hole principal.  It will tell you at least 17 people share the most common pair of initials (maybe $MJ$ is the most common) but not how many will share the *least* common.  Maybe *nobody* has the intials $ZX$.  It's obviously possible that *nobody* has matching initials.  As long as this is an imaginary country, maybe this country has made that illegal....

Comment: @fleablood thank you for stating me that I mustn't use the pigeon hole principle for this problem and why.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the beginning letters of first and last names are uniformly chosen from $26$ letters and chosen independently, $\frac 1{26}$ of the people will have matching first and last initials.  If the initial letters are chosen independently from some distribution the chance will be at least this (Imagine that $90\%$ of all names start with A and the rest start with other letters.  $81\%$ of people would then have initials AA).  Without more information about the distribution I don't think you can say more than this.  Maybe every first name starts with A and every last name starts with B.  Then nobody has matching initials.

Your calculation comes from the assumptions in my first sentences, but results in the number with both letters the same and a given letter of the alphabet.  I read the problem to ask how many matches there are, regardless of which letter a person uses.

Comment: @shaihorowitz:  If you don't assume the first and last names are distributed the same, you can have none.  I gave that example.

Comment: As the OP labelled this Pigeon Hole and used pigeon hole to explain this, I think he is asking the minimal number of people who share pair of initials. ... But I think it was badly worded, and possibly the OP misunderstood the question.

Comment: i.e.  If every first name began with A and every last name with be you would have $11$ million people with the same intials.  They'd all have initials A.B.

Comment: @fleablood:  that is not my reading of the problem as the examples all have one person with the same first and last initials.

Comment: Yeah... I reread the problem, and the OP does state "how many of them have their first and last name beginning with the same letter? (e.g. Alex Abus, Peter Pen etc.)".  Reading his/her answer a *third* time I see s/he is confusing "some letter/at least" with "all letters/at least".  i.e. at least one letter has 423 people with that as first initial (which is true).  Of that, all second initials have at least 16 people (which is false; Of that at least 16 people with  have *some* second initial that may be different.)

Comment: the exercise doesn't care about the letters after the first one, as long as it doesn't mention anything about them

Comment: The exercise was given with no more information, and I was confused too about how to solve it. But believe it or not, it was a question from a past exam in my university, so I guess the students had to answer it giving a number as a result and not by saying "more info needed". Therefore, I assume that the professor had an expected (right) answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Considering the Generalized Pigeonhole Principle:
>   at least
>   11.000.000 / 26 = 423.077 people have their first name beginning with the same letter.

Okay, Let's say that letter is $M$.  Let's say there are 526,217 people whose first name starts with $M$.

> From these 432.077 people, 
>   at least
>   432.077 / 26 = 16.619 people have their first AND last name beginning with the same letter.

But that letter does not have to be $M$.

That means among the 526,217 people whose first name starts with $M$, the most common letter for the last name (let's suppose it is $J$) will have at least $16,619$ people having.  It so let's suppose there are $27,145$ people with the initial M.J.

But it's perfectly conceivable that of the $526,217$ people whose first name begins with $M$ that NONE of them have last names beginning with $M$.

......

Thought experiment.  Let's say the King of this Country had a traumatic experience with comic books as child and decreed "As I *hate* Louis Lane, Lana Lang, and Peter Parker, it will be illegal in this country for anyone to have matching initials.  Any family which names their child with a first name that begins with the same letter as their last name shall be put to death."

In that case the answer is $0$.

Or if the King said "It will be required by law, that every child must have a first name with the same initial as the last name" then the answer would be $11,000,000$.

======== old answer =========

To answer "At least how many people share a pair of initials":

There are $26^2$ possible pairs of initials.  It's not possible for every pair of initials to have fewer than $\frac {11\times 10^6}{26^2}$ people with it, so at least one pair will have at least $\lceil \frac{10^6}{26^2} \rceil$ people with that pair.

No need to do it twice for each name.

Thus the most popular pair of initials will have *at least* that many.

...

BUT THAT WASN'T THE QUESTION

how many of them have their first and last name beginning with the same letter? (e.g. Alex Abus, Peter Pen etc.)

This is impossible to answer without knowing how the names are distributed.

As the initials $A$ and $M$ are much more common than $X$ or $Z$ and as the initials $A$ and $E$ are more common for first names than they are for last names, and as there is simply no-way any one of us can actually know the distribution, and as the distribution is so *obviously* NOT normally distributed, I simply can't see this as a valid question.

If we lived on another planet an we were *TOLD* initials are normally distributed given and JFOWGKEL JFKOW is just as common a name as ANTHONY SMITH then we'd expect one out of 26 people or $\frac {11,000,000}{26}$ people to have alliterative initials.

Comment: The exercise was given with no more information, and I was confused too about how to solve it. But believe it or not, it was a question from a past exam in my university, so I guess the students had to answer it giving a number as a result and not by saying "more info needed". Therefore, I assume that the professor had an expected (right) answer.

Comment: I would assume the professor is assuming that initials are normally distributed in which case 1 out of 26 will have their last name have the same initial as their first name.   Normally that's a fair assumption.  We assume it with questions like what is the probability of a girl or being born on a Friday and so on.  But for names... I think that's a poor assumption.

Comment: So, making this assumption (even it is poor) what would be the answer? If the answer should be 11.000.000 / 26  why would the professor bother writing in the question the part "and last name" as long as without it, the answer would be the same?

Comment: "bother writing in the question the part "and last name" as long as without it, the answer would be the same?"  It's not the same.  Everyone has a first name.  There are 26 possible last names, assuming normal distributions the probability of a persons last name having the same initial as their first name is 1/26.